# What do they call the link to the strut assembly?

Tags: struts

In [this video, *"What are Shocks? What are Struts? Which Does Your Car or Truck Use?"* the narrator says,](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2uRSfWkvRwU&t=794)

> *"when I was replace this whole strut assembly I knew that I was going to replace the link, so I left it attached to the strut"*

[image: Woman touching the "link"]

What do they call this "link"? I'm going to replace the strut assembly and I am wondering if I should replace that link too?

Comment: What's the make, model, and year of the car from which the strut was taken?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDITED:**

Upon viewing the video,  what she's talking about as a "link" is the sway bar link. In some situations is called an "end link" for the sway bar.