# Should I replace the sway bar link when replacing the strut assembly?

Tags: struts, swaybar

In [this video, *"What are Shocks? What are Struts? Which Does Your Car or Truck Use?"* the narrator says,](https://youtu.be/2uRSfWkvRwU?t=713)

> One thing I strongly recommend is if you get the assembly get the links, the links are attached to the assembly. [...] They wear real fast.

In this [question I was told the link in question is called an "end link for a sway bar"](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/q/87524/999). Is it necessary to replace the end link for the sway bar on a strut replacement. Is this also a Honda recommendation or common place? Is it easy to replace the end link for the sway bar later if needed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. One is independent from the other. The only time you should change it out is when it is worn out.

You should be able to easily replace the sway bar link. It is usually connected in just two place. In the case of your link, it has two ball ends, something like a tie rod end. It's fairly easy to tell when they are worn out. I made [this video](https://youtu.be/JfciZNJl38Y) last year which describes what to look for, so believe it is pertinent in your case.

On the other side, if the sway bar links come as an assembly, it may be just as economical or more economical to just replace it all at the same time. Check what the price is between the two. You may find it cheaper in the long run to just replace it together, mainly due to labor costs. It doesn't take much more for a mechanic to do the sway bar link while they're in there.

Comment: You're awesome. Quick on the answers. Thanks for all your help.